# How we set the rule in Firebase Realtime Database for every user Read data which is add by another one but user can delete only own data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**This is my Firebase Realtime Database Rule, suppose that here is two device  user A and B ,  A add data through App to firebase realTime Database , So B read that data which is Add by user A, Same B add data through app , So A read That Data, but both the user A or B delete only own Data which he enterd , A delete only own data and B delete only own data, but both user read data each other.. So which rule is apply here.
my rule is this**

```
  {
    "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "AllData": {
    "$uid": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

**and the data is sent to firebase is like this,here is my java code and my Application is Support Google and Facebook Signin**

```
 FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser ();
    String uid = mUser.getUid ();
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "AllData" ).child ( uid );
    myRef.keepSynced ( true );//for syncronize the firebase data
```

**and The data  from Firebase is this**

```
myapp-cbfba
|-- AllData
    |-WNOAsWDaVlQXq2DssE9AsUCw1jB3    <- Device A
    | |-M1UGU8pMJiNGd5zsG_r
    |   |-college:"ABES"
    |   |-contact:"956379797"
    |   |-dateTime:"03-03-2020 12:52:05"
    |   |-food: "Burger"
    |   |-name:"Vishal"
    |
    |-XiFNOWYYFHhjRdHx7AGOtchjN4x2   <- Device B
      |-M1UGqWNjWVIlbtluD6D
       |-college:"TMU"
       |-contact:"9578379797"
       |-dateTime:"03-03-2020 12:50:05"
       |-food: "Pizza"
       |-name:"Ankit"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
{
  "rules": { // rule for all
    "AllData": { // rule for data
      "$uid": { /// rule for userID 
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid" // return true/false for "==="
              // this is rule for writing. 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So if `"$uid === auth.uid"` return true/false base on uid is auth.uid.

Comment: Give me Complete Code Sir please.

Comment: That the complete rule for writing access inside the userID. U have to understand the firebase rule for writing the rest. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language

Comment: how we set return true false on database rule sir?

Comment: sir,in your rule,where is Read rule?

Comment: set it = true. Just like your current rule

Answer (score 0):

These rules allow the user to only access their own content:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: i have apply this rule but this is'nt working and, Sir i want,the data is read by everyOne but delete data by the ower of that data.